# How to change db name for yii2 Query Builder

Tags: yii2, query-builder

iam using multiple databases for my yii2 project.In my config file, I have the configuration like

```
       'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
        ],
        'db2' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db2',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
        ],
```

And i have a query like

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
                    ->select(['A.id', 'A.category_english', 'COUNT(B.category_id)'])
                    ->from(['A' => 'tbl_categories', 'B' => $filteredData])
                    ->where('A.id = B.category_id')
                    ->groupBy(['A.id', 'A.category_english'])
                    ->orderBy(['COUNT(B.category_id)'=>SORT_DESC]);
$data = $query->all();
```

The above query is fetching details from the first DB. How can I change that to the second? Where I can set the db name in query builder.

Comment: `$query->all(Yii::$app->db2)`

Comment: @Bizley  its working now.Thank you